# Filtering "downstream" related objects in Django's ORM?

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way to filter related objects in a class.  I am not talking about filtering BY related objects but instead filtering the related objects themselves IN a class.  Perhaps an example would better illustrate:

Say I have the following model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', null=True)
    isbn = models.CharField('ISBN',max_length=13)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)


class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_death = models.DateField('Died', null=True, blank=True)
```

I know how to do the straightforward filtering like getting all books for a specific genre:

```
books = Books.objects.filter(genre=1)
```

and then looping through this in the view:

```
{% for book in books %}
  {{book.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

But, is there a way to filter a queryset's related objects?  Let's say I have an already filtered author queryset and I ONLY want to list his books FROM a specific genre:

If I do this:

```
{% for book in author.books_set.all %}
  {{book.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

I get ALL of his books (as I would expect and want).

But, is there a way to do something like this:

```
{% for book in author.books_set.filter(genre=1) %}
  {{book.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

so that I am only getting a filtered list of the related objects?

I would prefer to do this in the view or as a class method as I do not like mixing logic in the template.

i.e.:

```
{% for book in author.books.filtered_genres %}
  {{book.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

But, I cannot seem to figure out the best and most pythonic (or djangonic :) ) way to do this.

I know I can 'build' a data structure myself in a view by looping through the various querysets and building what I want but I was looking to preserve the data model and relationships already defined.

Any thoughts on what I am trying to accomplish?  Or can I better elaborate on what I am trying to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply or concatenate multiple filters in querysets on the `Book` model:

```
books = Books.objects.filter(author='Bob', genre=1)
```

or

```
books = Books.objects.filter(author='Bob').filter(genre=1)
```

or - if you want to queryset related objects - you can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) method:

```
    author_genre_books = Author.objects.filter(author='Bob').prefetch_related(book_set__genre=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Doru:

I could not get this to work, got an error for

```
auths = Author.objects.filter(author='Bob').prefetch_related(book__genre=1)  

TypeError: prefetch_related() got an unexpected keyword argument 'book__genre'
```

But, you put me on the right path!!  I found the ***Prefetch*** method in the docs.
This is what I did and got it working as I needed:

```
auths = Author.objects.filter(author='Bob').prefetch_related(Prefetch('book_set', queryset=Book.objects.filter(genre=3), to_attr='filtered_books'))
```

then just used the following in template:

```
{% for book in author.filtered_books %}
  {{book.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

So, thanks for putting me on to the right path!